# Numpy Unpacking the Byte and Reversing the Order

Tags: python, numpy

I have a binary file with size of 10 MB, what I want to do with this file is to read bit by bit. In Python- Numpy, as far as I know we cannot read data bit by bit but byte. So, in order to read the data bit by bit, first I read the file using np.fromfile function then later unpack the byte into 8 bits using np.unpackbits function. Here is the script how I did it:

```
fbyte = np.fromfile(binar_file, dtype='uint8')
fbit = np.unpackbits(fbyte)
```

What I have in fbit is a long binary file but with reversing order in every 8 bits (MSB - LSB) e.g 10010011 ..., what I actually expected is in order LSB - MSB like this 11001001. By using for loop to flip the order of binary file every 8 bits will solve the problem, but it will take some time which I would like to avoid since I want to read thousand of files. So my question is, is there any way to unpack the bytes into bit but directly in order of LSB - MSB. Just as comparison, in Matlab this process is easy to do since there is Matlab function fread where I can specify bit configuration, e.g 'ubit1' for reading bit by bit and the result is as I expected --> LSB - MSB. Any help/hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post sample `fbyte`?

Comment: Don't think you need a loop there. Simply do : `np.unpackbits(fbyte).reshape(-1,8)[:,::-1]`. Add `.ravel()` to flatten.

Comment: @Divakar, Thank you so much. It works like a charm.  You really made my day!

Comment: Converted to a post. The timings seem pretty good to me and should be much faster than a loopy version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply reshape to `2D` keeping `8` columns and then flip those, like so -

```
np.unpackbits(fbyte).reshape(-1,8)[:,::-1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [1176]: fbyte
Out[1176]: array([253,  35, 198, 182,  62], dtype=uint8)

In [1177]: np.unpackbits(fbyte).reshape(-1,8)[:,::-1]
Out[1177]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Timings on one million elements array -

```
In [1173]: fbyte = np.random.randint(0,255,(1000000)).astype(np.uint8)

In [1174]: %timeit np.unpackbits(fbyte).reshape(-1,8)[:,::-1]
1000 loops, best of 3: 541 µs per loop
```

Seems crazy fast to me!

Answer (score 2):

In NumPy 1.17 and newer, `unpackbits` accepts a `bitorder` parameter that will accomplish this -- just pass `bitorder="little"` to the `np.unpackbits` call.